MTR statistics not agree with TCPDUMP file
I am trying to find some connection issues with my local lan. New to tcpdump so help needed!
The coomand run on my test VM which is 192.168.30.18:
tcpdump "host 192.168.0.100 or host 192.168.32.1" -w capture.cap

where 192.168.0.100 and 192.168.32.1 are physical devices.
Two MTR ran in two terminal gave me 7% packets loss for 192.168.0.100, no loss for 192.168.32.1.
TCPDUMP file attached shown that both 192.168.0.100 and 192.168.30.1 have quite alot packets loss, but no loss for 192.168.32.1 was shown by MTR.
Any thing I need to know to understand this inconsistancy?
Thanks guys,
YH
